# Is there a test case where this code can break?

Tags: c++

This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Given two arrays a and b, check whether they are similar.
Two arrays are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the arrays.

I wrote the following code to solve the problem. I tried to make some optimizations but it fails on a hidden test. Can anyone help me find where the code could break?

```
bool is_similar(vector<int> a, vector<int> b, int start){
    return memcmp(a.data() + start, b.data() + start, (a.size() - start) * sizeof(int)) == 0;
}
bool solution(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    int sizea = a.size(), sizeb = b.size();
    if(sizea != sizeb) return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizea; i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i]){
            auto it = find(b.begin() + i + 1, b.end(), a[i]);
            if(it != b.end()){
                swap(b[i], *it);
                return is_similar(a, b, i + 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When you say "I tried to make some optimizations but it fails on a hidden test." you mean you suspect the code is slow or that it contains a bug? Remember to write correct code first, and optimize it only after. Also, you can optimize your code by using `const vector<int>&` rather than just `vector<int>`.

Comment: I can't test the code right now, but usually problems happen in edge cases. Try these: `{}, {}`; `{}, {0}`; `{}, {0, 1, 2, 3}`; `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 2, 3, 0}`

Comment: It fails for `cout << solution({0, 1, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 4, 1, 3, 1}) << endl;`. It swaps `b` to `0 1 4 3 1` instead of `0 1 1 3 4`: https://godbolt.org/z/nKxevPE7q It fails when the first number in b which is not equal has a later duplicate.

Comment: Even smaller failing case: `{0, 0, 1}` and  `{1, 0, 0}`. (Tip: use small and systematic test cases. Small and simple inputs make it easier to figure out where things went wrong.)

Comment: is there any test case where `b.begin() + i + 1` is not going out of bounds?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Wont that be going up to `b.begin() + a.size()` which should yield the `b.end()` iterator?

Comment: @llualpu - I ran the available test cases and it was working fine. So I went ahead and made the optimizations. Then it failed on one hidden test after submission. I wasn't keeping track of the code before so I don't have the unoptimized version. But thank you. I will scrap everything off and start again.

Comment: @Cristian - It was guaranteed that no empty vectors will be passed to the arrays.

Comment: @mch Thank you so much! So I should check the next pair of values that are not alike and swap them instead. You are a lifesaver!

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you too. That is similar to what mch raised

Comment: If you want code review, you should try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

I started from scratch again and came up with a much better solution. Thank you all for your input. I'm loving this platform

The main problem was assuming the inputs were unique. This is the general flow of the initial code. A good test case to demonstrate the fault is when a = [0,1,1,3,4], b = [0,4,1,3,1]

1. Loop for the length of one of the arrays (they are of equal length)
2. Do nothing if the values are equal at the same index
3. If the values are not equal (now we are at index 1), search for 1 in array b and swap it with the current index. b becomes [0,1,4,3,1]
4. Now if we go on and call is_similar(a,b), it returns false.

Clearly if we swapped the contents at index 1 and 4, in array b, the arrays would be similar. That is why it fails.

A better approach is to collect the values at the indices where the values are different and determine if one swap is enough to make the two arrays similar. This is the code snippet.

```
bool solution(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    int sizea = a.size(), sizeb = b.size();
    if(sizea != sizeb) return false;
    int i= 0;
    vector<int> a1;
    vector<int> b1;
    for(i = 0; i < sizea; i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i]){
            a1.emplace_back(a[i]);
            b1.emplace_back(b[i]);
        }
    }
    
    if(a1.size() == 0) return true;
    
    if(a1.size() == 2) return a1[0] == b1[1] && a1[1] == b1[0];
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While it's great you want to share your snippet, it doesn't actually answer the question, and SO is very strictly a QA site. It's not a forum.

Comment: Yes I agree, you should add details about the edge test cases that failed and how you solved it. For the rest I think that the question is on-topic and not low-quality, so you deserved a better welcome

Comment: Thank you @hyde. I made an edit to the answer. I hope that is helpful